# Turkey e-Visa official website to avoid phishing

Tags: turkey, e-visas

I have come across many websites for applying for e-Visa, I am not sure which ones are are phishing and which one are original. Following are the ones I have got:

1. https://www.evisa.gov.tr/,  IP: 212.174.190.155, Maps to location: **turkey**
2. https://turkeyvisa.com.tr/, IP: 172.67.161.250, Maps to location: **USA**
3. https://konsolosluk.gov.tr/, IP: 212.174.190.160, Maps to location: **turkey**
4. https://www.turkey-travelpermit.com/, IP: 143.204.110.23, Maps to location: **Ireland**
5. https://www.visasturkey.com/, IP: 13.35.20.50, Maps to location: **Singapore**
6. https://www.onlinevisa.com/turkey-visa/, IP: 13.33.152.65, Maps to location: **USA**

Now I have the following concerns:

1. Most of them are appearing on first page when you google.
2. Most of them do not ask for even the email verification and take you to the checkout page.
3. Why would a government official website be hosted other than the country itself.
4. Why is there no place where you can officially authentically verify a website, if it is original or phishing.

Comment: anything that has gov. tr means it's an official website of the Turkish state.

Comment: `Why is there no place where you can officially authentically verify a website, if it is original or phishing.` this is a topic for Security SE. There is a lot to speak about. The websites you linked are not necessarily phishing, they are visa agencies with aggressive marketing tactics. And when I say *aggressive marketing* I think about those self-proclaimed power&gas telemarketers who claim to have the best prices ever, but in the end will just do the paperwork to switch your power company and gain commissions

Comment: Please note that `scams` are websites where you pay and get nothing, in this case you don't provide evidence that these websites will actually **steal** money. They could file the application on your behalf for an inflated price than applying at the *official* website

Comment: Ok again, after visiting the links it's clearer. Site #2 resembles the graphic appearence of official site (#1), except for: 1. the logo "e-visa" is SLIGHTLY different, so likely no trademark infringement, 2. the RoT half-moon logo is displayed as "helpful links" and is (not clearly) a disclaimer from affiliation. Site #2 has a Terms and Conditions page that displays the name of the company along with their tax number, so they are... uhm.... *somehow legit*. Your problem is that SEO puts **unofficial** sites before official

Comment: Note: you can also check embassy websites (usually they are not duplicate by scammers, but they may look like unprofessional): they should have links (as double verification, do not use it as the only check). Note: since some years, you can report such sites to Google (after many years they decided to stop listing such scam sites, but they focus mainly on US ESTA).

Comment: @Willeke True in general, but not here: the question asks about Turkey's version, and Turkey calls their e-visa implentation an **e-Visa**.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first link (https://www.evisa.gov.tr/) is the correct one. The `gov.tr` domain is a good indication that this is an official website from the Turkish government.

The second link (https://turkeyvisa.com.tr/) is quite suspicious (not a government domain, and if you start the application process it heavily pushes you towards paying extra for quicker processing before you even input your personal details) and I would not use it.

The third link (https://konsolosluk.gov.tr/) is also an official Turkish government site (again, see the `.gov.tr` domain). This one seems to be for general consular information rather than visas specifically - if you go to the 'visa' section, you are directed to the first link.

The fourth (https://www.turkey-travelpermit.com/) explicitly states on the homepage (although in a fairly bland part of the page that most people will skip over without reading) that it's neither part of nor affiliated with any government agency:

> This Website is a professional travel agency that aims to help individuals and companies complete the necessary travel authorization requests for short-term stays. There is a service fee, which includes expert help and assistance, and the fees charged by the Government. [www.turkey-travelpermit.com](http://www.turkey-travelpermit.com) is not affiliated with the Government or its sponsors. An application can also be submitted for a lower cost through the Government’s website here, though this would be without our professional review and expert service.

The fifth (https://www.visasturkey.com/) similarly has in its footer:

> Disclaimer: This company is not affiliated with the Turkish government. [www.visasturkey.com](http://www.visasturkey.com) is intended to help individuals and legal entities in their administrative travel paperwork to enter Turkey for a short term stay.

The sixth (https://www.onlinevisa.com/turkey-visa/) offers "expert review" and "Approved visa or money back" - these certainly aren't common services on an official visa portal. It also offers a "simplified application form", which may prompt you to ask "simplified in relation to what?" (presumably the official form). It also offers visa applications for several countries. That's not an immediate red flag ([VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/index.html) provide official visa application services for many countries, and there may well be other similar companies too), but it's not typical and is a sign that you might want to look for verification first.

Not all countries have a domain equivalent to `.gov.tr`, but [many do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gov#International_equivalents).

If you're struggling to work out which visa application sites are legitimate for a country, I'd suggest starting by searching for relevant government websites. The foreign ministry of a country is often a good start - visa information is usually easy to find, and (unlike visa application websites) there aren't typically private websites trying to look like they're some country's foreign ministry. A local embassy or consulate may also be a good place to start, for similar reasons.

> Why is there no place where you can officially authentically verify a website, if it is original or phishing.

That's not a simple task. Who determines whether a website is authentic, and ensures that decision is kept up to date?

Note that the non-official websites aren't necessarily *phishing* - many of them work perfectly well, they just take the information you put into their system and put it in the official application system, then charge you all the usual costs plus a "service fee" for themselves. They haven't provided a meaningful service in return for that fee, but you still get the visa just the same. So it's more like scalping than phishing. Of course, that's still not a good omen about their intentions, and I certainly don't recommend using them!

Comment: One additional piece of evidence: when you load a https:// site, it will send you something called an SSL certificate - which can be inspected in your web browser, if you like. The first and third sites have *extended validation* certificates explicitly stating that these sites are controlled by the Turkish government (specifically the foreign ministry) - meaning that a certificate authority (an organization who we assume we can trust) actually checked ownership. The other sites have more generic certificates. Which is to say: in this case, someone really did officially verify the websites.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: For better or for worse, EV certificates are [*de facto* dead](https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-really-really-dead/). You cannot rely on websites continuing to use them at this point, and because different companies with the same name can exist in different jurisdictions, they were arguably never all that useful to begin with (i.e. anyone can incorporate as "Stripe, Inc." and get an EV certificate under that name, as long as they don't do so in Delaware).

Answer (score 1):

I just learnt my lesson the hard way after my credit card got charged USD 151 for a visa that charges way lesser. This was on a site called https://turkeyvisa.com.tr.

I do not see any text indicating they aren't affiliated.

The  site did not show the amount being charged and my credit card got directly charged. I never received any receipt in my mailbox. Only an application processingwith transaction ID. My visa got processed within 3 minutes and I received a mail to that effect.

After realising that I'd been overcharged, i searched for scams relating to eVisa and realized that a lot of people have ended up paying huge sums through such sites. I did check the visa status on the govt site (eVisa.govt.tr) and while my visa is indeed a valid document, except my email ID I see on the govt site is actually a nonexistent one and the receipt that I can download shows a total charge of USD 44.50. I haven't been able to sleep the whole night after seeing all this mess. I don't think the extra 105.50 USD I ended up paying will be returned. I did report such sites to Google and I see that 2 of those are non-functional now.

But turkeyvisa.com.tr is still functional despite my reporting it multiple times since yesterday. I have blocked my card and have raised a dispute for fraudulent transaction, but I doubt if I'll get the money back. I wish there could be something like a one-time password for international transactions too so that people could verify the amount being charged on the card. This was truly horrible and I'm unable to get it off my head! :(

Comment: Why did you enter your credit card details *before* you knew how much you were going to be charged? **Huge** red flag, IMHO

Comment: 151-44.50=106.50, not 105.50

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't look well enough. At the bottom of that site's home page is a link for "Terms and Conditions." The first entry on the linked [Terms and Conditions page](https://turkeyvisa.com.tr/terms/) discloses the name, address, and tax information of the private company that operates this site.